# Mutlivariable integral, How to compute it?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics

Can anybody please tell me, how to evaluate a multivariate integral with a gaussian weight function.
$$\mathcal{Z_{n}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_{1}dx_{2}dx_{3}dx_{4}...dx_{n}\exp(-\frac{a}{2}\sum_{j}x_{j}^2)\times f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}....x_{n})$$ 
where $f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}....x_{n})=\Pi_{j} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+i\,b(x_{j}^2-x_{j+1}^2)^2)}}$, and $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Also we have the condition $x_{n+1}=x_{1}$.

I need a hint to solve this integral. This is how I proceeded,

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{Z_{n}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Pi_{j=1}^{n} dx_{j}  \exp{\Bigg(-\frac{a}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^2-\frac{1}{2}\log{\Big(1+i b(x_{j}^2-x_{j+1}^2)^{2}\Big)\Bigg)}}
\end{eqnarray}

Now the integral is of the form of the canonical partition function integrated over the configuration space. Hence the integral can be identified as an $n-$particle partition of the canonical ensemble, which is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{Z}_{n}= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Pi_{j=1}^{n} dx_{j}  e^{-\beta \mathcal{H}},
\end{eqnarray}
where $$\mathcal{H}=\Bigg(\frac{a}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^2+\frac{1}{2}\log{\Big(1+i b(x_{j}^2-x_{j+1}^2)^{2}\Big)\Bigg)}.$$ and $\beta=1$.
Then I got stuck !

Comment: I asked it there, but no response !!!!

Comment: Then I thought that Physicists may do better than Mathematicians !

Comment: Given the function $f(x_j)$, seems to me that this can only be solved numerically. Where did you find such an integral?

Comment: @SijoJoseph: The integral does not converge for any $n$. Are you sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the exponential function should read $\exp\left(-\sum_{j} x_j^2\right)$. (More like a Gaussian distribution.) Then the integral converges because of the upper bound given by a Gaussian distribution. I think you are familiar with the integration trick for the Gaussian distribution (changing from Cartesian to Polar coordinates). I am afraid that this does not work here because of the term under the square root. :-(

Comment: @Tobias and DumpsterDoofus thank you for pointing out  the error. The exponential should contain a minus sign inside the bracket. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos I found this integral in relation to the entanglement dynamics in a bipartite system which is classically chaotic. I am trying to  find an analytical expression for the von neumann  entropy of entanglement. I am able to formulate my problem in terms of this integral. Now I got stuck since I don't know the tricks to resolve this type of integrals.

Comment: If you have an even number of integral variables you can decompose the integral into a sequence of 2D-integrals (because of $\exp(-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2)=\exp(-x_1^2-x_2^2)\exp(-x_3^2-x_4^2)$ and only 2 vars under the root. The trick for the Gaussian is: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2-y^2)dxdy=\int_{r=0}^\infty \exp(-r^2) 2\pi rdr =[-\pi\exp(-r^2)]_0^\infty = \pi.$ Pityingly the root does not fit in there.

Comment: I used a similar reversed procedure to arrive at this integral. This integral corresponds to an entangled state, actually the root term contains entanglement. Hence we cannot split the integral into parts. What I did is, I took the exponential of the  logarithm of the square root term. Then I can write it as a partition function with some pseudo-Hamiltonian.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The pairs are interwoven. So, no splitting. It is a pity. **One** more thing. Is $i:=\sqrt{-1}$? Then you could/should explicitly state it. Sorry, that I cannot be of more help.